# How to export large table data into different files in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, migration

I have a table which contains 1 million lines and need to export into different files which containing 100k lines each.

sample_01.sql ,sample_02.sql and so on

How can we take export like this in oracle?

Comment: To be honest I would just create 1 file for the whole table then split it to 10 smaller ones.

Comment: the usage of the word export is confusing here. In oracle  this means extraction of structures and data with special tools (exp, expdp) into files that have a special format. The content of these kind of files can only me imported into Oracle databases. So I assume you want to write the output of one or more SQL statements into text files. Which tool do you use to query the database? Why do you want to extract this data and why do you want to split it??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use utl_file and a for loop for this assignment. Then you can open and write one line per file. You should also let people know what a Lakh line is.

Answer (score 1):

1 Lakh = 100,000.
10 Lakh = 1 million.

Question: *Why* do you want to do this?

A million row database table is *not* that significant these days.

A million row *file* won't give any modern file system much difficulty either.

OK, you won't find many editor *programs* that will allow you to usefully *open* such a file but - again - why would you *want* to?

Files, in this context, should be seen as a Transport media, *not* something that you'd want to actively work with except, perhaps, to load them into another database!

Comment: i want to insert that rows in MySQL .it is part of migration i'm wasting so much time there taking that table export and splitting into different into different files.

Comment: Use the MySQL version of SQL-Loader to import the data. A 10M row file isn't a problem if you use the right tools.